# KafkaException error when using MessageHub Service

Tags: ibm-cloud, message-hub

Using the Message Hub service recently, I have discovered that previously working apps have begun failing with a `KafkaException` or `Failed to update metadata`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

As of the 3rd March, port 9094 has been switched off, as documented in the MessageHub docs:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/MessageHub/index.html#messagehub063

and the correct port to use instead is port 9093. Misuse of the 9094 port has been known to cause the above errors.